# Como executar ação de botão dentro de Listview Android C#

Tags: c#, android, listview, button

Criei uma aplicação de android de consulta de dados, onde possuem os layout e adapter prontos para fazer crud de dados, porém a operação de crud funcionou quando dado é inserido e consultado. não consegui realizar uma alteração de dado através de botão que está dentro de uma listview de dados consultados. as ferramentas que usei é o android C# e banco de dado sqlite.

Como seleciona os parâmetro de dado e alterar o valor de 0 para 1 quando botão dentro de listview for clicado? obs: Botão está dentro de um adapter, não em uma activity.

Obrigado.

Comment: Por gentileza poste o código relevante a sua pergunta.

Comment: Já tentou botao.setOnClickListerner(){ } ?